# images not showing when opening index.html from dist folder

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-style-loader

I am using webpack 4.8 with react for automating few tasks for production environment.

Currently in my /dist folder I have index.hml, bundler.css, bundler.js but I don't know if I also need to copy assets folder into /dist folder using webpack or shall I just reference from my /dist/index.html into /src/assets/img using some constant as absolute path (define some baseUrl).

My whole structure looks like this:

```
/dist
/src
  /assets
    /img
```

Anyone knows what is the best way achieve such thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should copy `assets` into `/dist` and reference to it in `index.html`

You can use [copy-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/copy-webpack-plugin) (ad It to your package.json)

```
new CopyWebpackPlugin([
    { from: 'src/assets', to: 'assets' },
    ...
]);
```

Comment: how do I do this?

Comment: also in my code I am referencing assets smth like for ex: ./src/assets/img while if i copy assets on /dist then I dont have /src there, how do I deal with this?

Comment: @Mizlul I update my answer. For your second question - you can use for instance webpack-dev serwer with hmr - look close on this project (foder: config) https://github.com/gdi2290/angular-starter

Comment: do I need to have two webpack files one for dev and one for prod for this?

Comment: you can put "IF" stements inside one file - how ever - as you can see - for bigger projects is better to have separate files...

Comment: @Mizlul In fact angular-starter is not typical project... it is FRAMEWORK - you can use it "instead of reinvent the wheel"

Answer (score 0):

You could just make a relative path via ./SOME/PATH
One dot for one folder to go back